# Error: gcov: error: missing argument to '-x'

Tags: c, gcc, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I try to find coverage with lcov. But I am stuck in this error.

I use this command to find coverage.

```
lcov --capture --directory . --output-file main2.info
```

```
Capturing coverage data from .
Subroutine read_intermediate_text redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2623.
Subroutine read_intermediate_json redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2655.
Subroutine intermediate_text_to_info redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2703.
Subroutine intermediate_json_to_info redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2792.
Subroutine get_output_fd redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2872.
Subroutine print_gcov_warnings redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2900.
Subroutine process_intermediate redefined at /usr/bin/geninfo line 2930.
Found gcov version: 10.4.0
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
Found 2 data files in .
Processing main.gcda
gcov: error: missing argument to '-x'
geninfo: ERROR: GCOV failed for /home/somiha/wf-0.41-28.fc36.src/wf-0.41/src/main.gcda!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check versions with the command:
e.g

`gcc --version`

`gcov --version`

`lcov` returns the error if versions are different.